# blackberry screen orientation change

Tags: blackberry, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

i want to set my application in Portrait mode as default . so how to implement it ?
all screen of the application set default as Portrait mode ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this BlackBerry UI guide:
[Specifying the orientation and direction of the screen](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Specifying_display_direction_of_screen_647783_11.jsp)

Comment: y u gave nagative vote for my all question ? if u dont like my question than dont give me but ...

Comment: wasn't me but probably because it is a trivil question and because it can be found easy if you search for it.

Comment: @juanmabaiu above is not for you , it is for "Rafael Osipov" .

Comment: Hello, Hitarth. I voted -1 for this question. The reason is simple. Answer to your question is on the first link in google search results when you search for [blackberry display orientation](http://www.google.ru/search?q=blackberry+display+orientation).

Comment: @Hitarth I know. But you realize that Rafael Osipov said what I have already told you?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov i know but everyone have not same strangth to search in google . you r reputed person you have to motivate new user . i posted this question here bz it was argent and i couldn't find it in 5 min so ..

Answer (score 0):

This set default portrait mode:

```
public void disableOrientationChange()
{

    int directions = Display.DIRECTION_NORTH;
    UiEngineInstance engineInstance = Ui.getUiEngineInstance();
    if (engineInstance != null)
    {
        engineInstance.setAcceptableDirections(directions);
    }
}
```